# Deleting a line from a multiline flxText

Tags: haxeflixel

How can I delete the first line from a flxText?
I have tried `text.textField.replaceText(0, text.textField.getLineLength(0), "");` but it only works once. I have also tried keeping count of the line that's being deleted and it doesn't work either.

**edit:** I would like to reopen this question to specify that I want to take into account both newlines and word wrap.

Comment: Does the text itself contain the line breaks or are you relying on word wrapping for the lines?

Comment: The text contains line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the text contains the line breaks why not just split the text on `\n`, remove the lines you no longer need, and then set the text to the joined lines.

```
var lines = flText.text.split("\n");
lines.shift(); // removes the first line
flText.text = lines.join("\n");
```